# Antlr not showing gui

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, cmd, antlr

i'm working on windows and visual studio and my goal is to try to define a grammar to recognize the parts of some phrases 
i followed this guide 
https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Getting+Started+with+ANTLR+v4

letter by letter, and when i do

grun Hello r -gui cmd is not showing nothing, it's not showing any type of error 
How can i solve this?
Thank you all!!!

PS the guide tells 
Add antlr-4.5-complete.jar and the link download antlr-4.2-complete, i tryied with this jar and with 4.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After executing `grun Hello r -gui` you have to type in some input for your parser to process. When you're done, don't press return, but press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> for Windows (for *nix, you press <kbd>CTLR</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)

Comment: exactly i typed
hello parrt
^Z
but nothing happen :(

Comment: ok i tryied one more time and finally it works thanks for you help

Comment: i'm writing here again not for help but because someone just like me could come here searching for antlr and visual studio, i've found a perfect guide  that works at 100% with antlr4 and visual studio 2010
https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/wiki